# PHP Within JavaScript: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a PHP function that returns an integer.

```
myFunction($myParameter);
```

The last line of this function returns the variable within an `intval` to ensure there's nothing else coming back.

When I do

```
<?php echo myFunction($myParameter) ?>
```

I get back an integer value in the browser:

> 4

So I want to embed this as a parameter to a JavaScript function. So I did:

```
<SCRIPT>
   setJSValue(<?php echo myFunction($myParameter); ?>);
</SCRIPT>
```

Chrome returns:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Or, alternatively,

```
<SCRIPT>
   setJSValue(<?php echo json_encode(myFunction($myParameter)); ?>);
</SCRIPT>
```

and

```
<SCRIPT>
   setJSValue(JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode(myFunction($myParameter)); ?>));
</SCRIPT>
```

Both of which give:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I understand that the most common answer to this is that there is an illegal character in the string. I deleted the script, the code ran fine, then re-typed the command manually.

This ought to be straightforward. There has to be something I'm missing. Thank you in advance.

Edit to address questions from commenters:

The "myfunction" is as simple as it gets:

```
  function setCurrentPick(pick)
  {
    currentPick = pick;
  }
```

Where `currentpick` is in the parent context of the function.

Encasing the method in quotes gives the ILLEGAL error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: For once try this:- <SCRIPT>
   setJSValue("<?php echo myFunction($myParameter); ?>");
</SCRIPT>

Comment: Post what the browser is getting when you do `setJSValue(<?php echo myFunction($myParameter); ?>);`

Comment: Can you show your setJSValue function?

Comment: are you sure **myFunction** return interger and doesn't have any **whitespace** charactor???

Comment: @littleibex: The php function returns: `intval($x);` so I am fairly sure it's delivering just the value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. I appreciate you taking the time.

The problem was the method I called in PHP contained an echo message I had put in there a while back for debugging purposes. Although it was *returning* just an integer, it was rendering display text which confused the JS. The debug text came out in the middle of some other trace messages so I missed it.

Thanks again.